# what is the distributions of the random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If moment generating function is $m(t)=[(1/3)e^{t}+(2/3)]^{5}$,

then what is the distributions of the random variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe work backwards. The mgf of a sum of independent random variables is the product of the mgf. So our mgf is the mgf of a sum $X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_5$ of $5$ independent random variables with mgf $(1/3)e^t +2/3$. Now do we recognize this? Hint: What is the mgf of a random variable which is $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$?

Comment: thanks~ Binomial distribution~

Comment: Prof. Nicolas would you see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760451/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-j-to0-lim-k-to-infty-frackjj-ek/760457?noredirect=1#comment1580947_760457), please? I really hope you can answer it for me. Thank you. (-^〇^-)

Comment: Got back, saw it. The answer that was given is correct. For fixed $j$, the inner limit is $0$, so the full limit is $0$.