# Find the limit of the sequence if it converges, otherwise state divergence.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of the sequence given by
$$\frac{10+12n+20n^4}{7n^4 + 5n^3 - 20}$$

I think the answer is $\frac{20}{7}$ after dividing, but is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, because
$$\frac{20n^4+12n+10}{7n^4 + 5n^3 - 20}=\frac{20+\frac{12}{n^3}+\frac{10}{n^4}}{7+\frac5n-\frac{20}{n^4}}\to\frac{20+0+0}{7+0-0}=\frac{20}7$$
by the arithmetic of limits.

You should see this method works in general for a fraction of two polynomials, just divide $n^d$, where $d$ is the degree of the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes right!

$$\frac{10+12n+20n^4}{7n^4+5n^3-20}=\frac{\frac{10}{n^4}+\frac{12}{n^3}+20}{7+\frac5n-\frac{20}{n^4}}$$
and pass to the limit.

**Remark:** There's a simple way to find the limit at $\infty$ for a fraction of two polynomials: it suffices to take the monomial of highest degree for the numerator and denominator, hence applying this we find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10+12n+20n^4}{7n^4+5n^3-20}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{20n^4}{7n^4}=\frac{20}7$$

Comment: Thanks! And one more question suppose there was a n in the denominator was under a square root, would that mean it diverges?

Comment: We say that a sequence diverges if it hasn't a limit or tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Which limit do you want? As $n \to 0$ this goes to the limit $-\frac 12$.

I put this as an answer because the other answers were up, and there are alternatives to those.

Comment: $n$ usually marks natural numbers or integers, almost never reals

Comment: @user2345215 That doesn't stop $n$ decreasing to zero. I put this up, because a failure to specify is a mathematical error, and care needs to be taken with limits, even if these things do seem obvious.

Comment: @user2345215 You are confusing $\mathbb{N}$ and $n$. $n$ is just a variable in this expression, and is almost certainly a real number (in this question). Not sure why this is downvoted.

Comment: @mathguy Almost certainly not, see the word "sequence" in the title. This interpretation makes no sense.

Comment: @user2345215 Oh I missed the title.

Comment: @user2345215 I missed the title too. But to be pedantic, the constant sequence where every term is zero tends to zero. I agree that is probably not what was contemplated. And sometimes we want $n\to - \infty$.

Comment: Maybe I created this confusion, when I edited the post to be "clear". OP originally specified no text, just what was in the title, so I fixed it now.

Comment: @user2345215 Understood.

Comment: How about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760451/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-j-to0-lim-k-to-infty-frackjj-ek)?